# TSql Return column based on partition and rownumber

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rank, row-number, partition-by

I have a SQL server table where I'm attempting to get a computed column -
 MyPartition - indicating the number of the partition based on a variable @segment. For example, if @segment = 3 then the following output would be true.

```
RowID  | RowName    | MyPartition
------ | -----------| -------
1      | My Prod 1  | 1
2      | My Prod 2  | 1
3      | My Prod 3  | 1
4      | My Prod 4  | 2
5      | My Prod 5  | 2
6      | My Prod 6  | 2
7      | My Prod 7  | 3
8      | My Prod 8  | 3
9      | My Prod 9  | 3
10     | My Prod 10 | 4
```

What I have thus far is something like:

```
SELECT 
    RowId,
    RowName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RowId ORDER BY RowId ASC) AS MyPartition
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY RowId
```

But as you can guess the partition just partitions on the rowid giving all values of mypartition = 1. I am unsure how to structure the partition by clause to achieve this.

Comment: Are you trying to put at most @segment elements within a given grouping? That is, based on your example above, it appears that you want three 1's, three 2's, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
CEILING(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowId ASC) / 3.0)
```